# postgresql query error which doesnt return the table

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I want to view the datas in the table in display using C#,but my function in postgresql returns error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function view1() line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

Postgresql Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION View1 ()
RETURNS table (X varchar,Y varchar,Provinces varchar)
  AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   RETURN
   ( SELECT "X","Y","Provinces" FROM public.point) ;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Kindly Help Me.

Comment: Presumably it should be `RETURN QUERY` not only `RETURN` in the functions body.

Comment: still error persists

Comment: Please post code of function call in your application.

Comment: @JoelAbraham whether it is same error or different.